# Empty story clicks, likes and comments in Facebook insights for mobile app posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

When looking at Insights for a Facebook app page (for a mobile application, either via the app page or the Graph API), the Traffic -> Stream Publish page has a value called Story Clicks. From a recently published mobile app, I see 26 published stories, 2732 story impressions, but 0 story clicks. Does anyone know what the story clicks is tracking, or how it is defined?

Also on the same page, there is a graph for Likes and Comments, both of which are showing up as 0, although at least one person has commented and liked all of the posts that have been made so far. Why would the likes and comments be 0? (Note that the posts were either status updates with a location, a photo post or a video post, all done by the app via the Graph API).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must know that facebook insights are not updated in real time mode. So you must wait for some time to see the insights for particular time. 
Story clicks are the clicks on your post from users who have seen your post. And 2732 view is not a big deal. The average CTR (Click through Rate) can very between 0,00015 to 0,001. So if your story is not very interesting it might not have any clicks if the one who clicked on your story was you. 
Likes and comments are the comments made on your app posts. This section also doesn't update in real time so waiting for some time can bring everything to their places. 
[Here is](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/399262596797358) some resource that can help you.